# How can I make my pipeline execute the imputation stage?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I'm trying to run a basic model but it seems as though the imputation stage of my pipeline is failing, and I don't really understand why.

Here's the minimal replicable code

If you'd like you can find the data for [x](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1njAn9asA33_n-zJlpFvgfsdQres0Ku5r/view?usp=sharing) and [y](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vJ8mbxw32mc-cq6Vto33S-frvKoSp2fd/view?usp=sharing). Originally they were in a public file that I can easily link you to, but I transformed them a little so I'll use the edited output to cut down on the code you have to read. I can easily link to the original code and dataset if need be, however.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier,AdaBoostRegressor,AdaBoostClassifier,RandomForestRegressor
from category_encoders import CatBoostEncoder,CountEncoder,TargetEncoder,SumEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import datetime as dt

x = pd.read_csv("/home/user/Python Practice/Working/Playstore/x.csv",index_col=("Unnamed: 0"))
y = pd.read_csv("/home/user/Python Practice/Working/Playstore/y.csv",index_col=("Unnamed: 0"))

# Set up Imputers
strat = ["mean","median","most_frequent","constant"]
num_imp = SimpleImputer(strategy=strat[0])
obj_imp = SimpleImputer(strategy=strat[2])

# Set up the scaler
sc = StandardScaler()

# Set up Encoders
cb = CatBoostEncoder()
oh = OneHotEncoder()

# Set up columns
obj = list(x.select_dtypes(include="object"))
num = list(x.select_dtypes(exclude="object"))
cb_col = [i for i in obj if len(x[i].unique())>30]
oh_col = [i for i in obj if len(x[i].unique())<10]

# Col Transformation
col = make_column_transformer((cb,cb_col),
                              (obj_imp,cb_col),
                              (oh,oh_col),
                              (obj_imp,oh_col),
                              (num_imp,num),
                              (sc,num))

model = AdaBoostRegressor(random_state=(0))

#Second Pipeline
run = make_pipeline((col),(model))
run.fit(x,y)
print("The score is",run.score(x,y))
```

The model crashes at the `.fit` stage with the error message: `ValueError: Input contains NaN`. Why woud it do this when I've imputed? And how can I resolve it?

Comment: Some of your categorical columns were neither imputed nor transformed using your sample data: 'Type' and 'Content Rating'. Is this intended?

Comment: @BillHuang   Unintended. Thanks for that. The `oh_col` should have been `len(x[i].unique())<10` rather than `>`. I'll fix it. The error is still there though. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any reason to stick to `make_column_transformer` and `make_pipeline`? It does not seem to be working well with the Imputer on object columns. The Scaler also behaved strangely in the pipeline, giving `ValueError` which does not appear if a data pipeline is not used. If there is no reason, then I think I've got a fix....

Answer (score 0):

I am using pandas v1.1.3 and sklearn v0.23.2.

I guess the main problem is caused by `CatBoostEncoder`. It [requires column y as input](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/catboost.html), so it may not work with `make_column_transformer()`, at least not according what the [manual](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer.html) describes. Its output format is also different from other transformers as shown in the fixed code.

### Fix

First, your index was messed up and must be fixed after loading.

```
x.index[10470:10475]
Out[34]: Int64Index([10470, 10471, 10473, 10474, 10475], dtype='int64')

# fix
x.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
y.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Second, make the OneHotEncoder output a dense array.

```
oh = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
```

Third, break down the pipeline.

```
# 1. Impute
x[num] = num_imp.fit_transform(x[num])
x[obj] = obj_imp.fit_transform(x[obj])
assert x.isnull().sum().sum() == 0  # make sure no missing value exists

# 2. Transform
x = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(sc.fit_transform(x[num])),
               cb.fit_transform(x[cb_col], y),
               pd.DataFrame(oh.fit_transform(x[oh_col]))
               ], axis=1)
```

Finally, train and evaluate the model directly. The shape conversion suppresses warnings.

```
model = AdaBoostRegressor(random_state=0)
model.fit(x.values, y.values.reshape(-1))
print("The score is", model.score(x, y.values.reshape(-1)))
```

Result:

```
The score is 0.6329093797171869
```

### Additional Info

I have tried to ignore the third-party `CatBoostEncoder` and just use `OneHotEncoder` on all object columns.

```
col = make_column_transformer(
    (num_imp, num),
    (obj_imp, obj),
    (sc, num),
    (oh, obj),
)
```

However, the attempt failed in many strange manners I don't understand.

- `oh` failed with `ValueError: Input contains NaN`.
- `sc` failed with `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').` This happens when only `x[num]` are passed into the pipeline, plus that `obj_imp` and `oh` were turned off.

This is the main reason why I decided to give up on pipeline, as the behavior of transformers in the pipeline deviates greatly from what I observed in the fixed code.

Comment: Thanks. You're a gem. It's pretty late here so I can't attempt your fix, but I'll try it first thing tomorrow and tell you the result. Thanks again.